# Xamarin Forms How to change the background Colour of an custom animated page renderer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-animation

I have a custom page renderer to create animation from the right to left slide for my page navigation. There is a problem that the background of the animation is either white or black depending on the `Android` setting of dark or white theme. I want the animation background color to be the same color as my actual page-background color.

Doing `Animation.BackroundColor = Color.Red` is obsolete and deprecated...

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace uCue_Game.Droid
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public CustomPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            var myValue = Preferences.Get("ModelAnimation", false);
            if (myValue)
            {
                var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
                Android.Views.Animations.Animation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(metrics.HeightPixels, 0, 0, 0)
                {
                    Duration = 1500
                };
                Animation = translateAnimation;
                translateAnimation.Start();
            }

            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Preferences.Set("ModelAnimation", true);
```

If you would like to re-produce this, add the code above into `*.Android` project as a class. Create 2 blank content pages and then before doing `PushAsync` use the preferences line to enable the animation. You'll be able to see the black or white background as you switch between each page.

Comment: Given that Android's Animation doc not only says "deprecated", but says *"None of window animations are running with background color."*, unclear whether this is possible. See if Xamarin.Android has equivalent to [Animation.setBackdropColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation#setBackdropColor(int)). Might be either `BackdropColor = ...;` or `SetBackdropColor(...);`.

Comment: Yes, per the [Animation.BackgroundColor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.animations.animation.backgroundcolor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13), the `setBackgroundColor` has being deprecated in Xamarin.Android 13. You can try [Animation.BackdropColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.animations.animation.backdropcolor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) which works as Steve suggested.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT After reading the Microsoft Docs and the Android once this is supposed to exist but in `Android.Views.Animations` namespace but I have the using for it and the property isn't there. `setBackdropColor` or `BackdropColor`...

Comment: What is your `API` level?

Comment: Android 5.0 (API Level 21) and I've just noticed that the Backdrop was added in level 33. I see, can I just change my API level and it will work after restart?

Comment: There is a problem with API level 33, not even my Emulators support that version....

Comment: If your Emulators doesn't support `API 33`, then it would fail to use the property `setBackdropColor` or `BackdropColor`.